# How do I Limit the number of pages a non-subscriber can see?

Tags: users

Hi want to make a site like Quora_com, 
If a new users vists the site through external link, he or she will be shown the full content.

However, as the user tries to access a new Webpage they will be shown with a SignUP/Login page that is mandatory and cannot be dismissed.

Anyway to do this? Any plugin or code? please help, i am very much in need.

Comment: You can use cookies. If a user visits single page, show him full post and set a cookie. He tries to visit another page or comes back later, check for cookie and show login/register form. You can get more info from [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Cookies)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no absolute secure way. But for a start, you could check the HTTP-REFERER variable (http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-http-referer-variable/) to see where the visitor is coming from.